# What is the difference between default view and UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uiview

I am using Google Map in my app. When I use `self.view = map` that map in a GMSMapView all is working okay.

But when I create an UIView with IBOutlet (thing with name mapView) and use to show map with markers, all the things i get is just an empty UIView.

So, what's difference is between `self.view = map` and `self.mapView = map`? What should I do?

Comment: Try setting class of self.mapview to GMSMapView

Comment: @sanman I did it, but just show the default google map without any customize that I did.

Comment: Please post the code showing your customization and initialization of the map so that we know what exactly may be causing the problem. What you can also try is programmatically create the google map view and add it as a sub view to your self.mapView with same bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You must use GMSMapViewDelegate and your mapView must be as GMSMapView

```
import GoogleMaps
class ViewController: UIViewController,GMSMapViewDelegate{
     @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
     override func viewDidLoad() {
          self.mapView.delegate = self 
     }
}
```

Comment: NO man, this didn't work. self.view work correctly.but using mapView outlet doesn't work.

Comment: Why when I use self.view there is no problem, but when use a IBOutlet , there is no response?!?

Comment: @ShervinJam do you connect your custom UIView to your IBOutlet and set class of that view in storyboard to GMSMapView ???